# not understanding how ref.push() works

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to push new data to the provided reference and I tried this:

```
let friends=ref(config.db,`users/${username}/friends`)
friends.push().set({
   [fr]: 1,
  });
```

this is the error i got
`TypeError: friends.push is not a function`

tried this too

```
set(ref(config.db, "users/" + username + "/friends").push(),{
 [fr]: 1,
});
```

this too

```
ref(config.db, "users/" + username + "/friends").push({
 [receiver_]: 1,
});
```

Can anyone explain how push works I read the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-push) and copied what was there

Comment: The article you linked to doesn't use `ref(...)`, it uses `ref.child(...)` - so change your code to `const friends = ref.child(config.db, 'users/' + username + '/friends' )` (also, are you verifying that `username` does not contain invalid chars?)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to add data to the Realtime Database, please use the following lines of code:

```
var db = firebase.database().ref();
var friends = db.child('users/${username}/friends');
var pushData = friends.push();
pushData.set({
    fr: 1
});
```

So you have to call push on a reference object and then call `set()`. Please also note that there is no need to use `[` and `]` when defining the fields.

Comment: can you tell me what packages need to be imported? right now i am doing this annd its not working
```const { initializeApp } = require("firebase/app");
const { getDatabase } = require("firebase/database"); 
const config={apikey:XXXXX and so on}
const firebase = initializeApp(config);
const db = getDatabase(firebase);
const refer=db.database().ref()

```
and i am getting TypeError: db.database is not a function

do i need to use ```firebase-admin```?

edit: and i am using [ ] for using variable as key

Comment: You cannot use firebase-admin in web client code. It's not supported for use in browsers. It works on Node.js only server side,